# convert webservice from rpc to document literal

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, nusoap

Can someone explain how to convert the following webservice in to a document literal from rpc encoded?

Ive tried just changing the rpc to document and encoded to literal.

But the wsdl doesn't display as wsdl:definitions just as definitions and looking at the document from ibm http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-whichwsdl/ it doesn't look as if this is the way to do it? Can someone explain how to do this? thanks

```
require_once("nuSOAP/lib/nusoap.php");
$namespace = "http://localhost/nusoaphelloworld/index.php";

// create a new soap server
$server = new soap_server();

  // configure our WSDL
  $server->configureWSDL("HelloExample");

  // set our namespace
  $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

 //Register a method that has parameters and return types
 $server->register(
 // method name:
 'HelloWorld',
 // parameter list:
 array('name'=>'xsd:string'),
 // return value(s):
 array('return'=>'xsd:string'),
 // namespace:
 $namespace,
 // soapaction: (use default)
 false,
 // style: rpc or document
 'rpc',
 // use: encoded or literal
 'encoded',
 // description: documentation for the method
'Simple Hello World Method');

 //Create a complex type
 $server->wsdl->addComplexType('MyComplexType','complexType','struct','all','',
  array( 'ID' => array('name' => 'ID','type' => 'xsd:int'),
 'YourName' => array('name' => 'YourName','type' => 'xsd:string')));

 //Register our method using the complex type
 $server->register(
 // method name:
 'HelloComplexWorld',
 // parameter list:
 array('name'=>'tns:MyComplexType'),
 // return value(s):
 array('return'=>'tns:MyComplexType'),
 // namespace:
 $namespace,
 // soapaction: (use default)
 false,
 // style: rpc or document
 'rpc',
 // use: encoded or literal
 'encoded',
 // description: documentation for the method
 'Complex Hello World Method');

 //Our Simple method
 function HelloWorld($name)
{
 return "Hello " . $name;
}

//Our complex method
 function HelloComplexWorld($mycomplextype)  
{
 return $mycomplextype;
}

 // Get our posted data if the service is being consumed
// otherwise leave this data blank.
$POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';

// pass our posted data (or nothing) to the soap service
$server->service($POST_DATA);
exit();
```